# PHP Remove \ from a string that is pulled from DB

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I built a blog that uses a WYSIWYG editor(TinyMCE). You build a blog post, post it, and it is stored in a MySQL Database. The post then gets pulled out by another page. Simple stuff for most of you I'm sure.

It worked fine on my test server, so I switched it to another server, and now the images don't pull through properly on the view blog page.

I inspected the img URL and it looked like this.

```
<img src="\"/img/parking1.png\"" alt="\"\"">
```

I haven't written a method to do it, but it seems to be escaping () the quote marks.

It didn't do this on my last server, and worked fine, so I am assuming it's a server (hosting) security thing.

I tried to remove them, replace them with blank:

```
$cleanpost = str_replace('\', '',$post);
```

Where `$post` is the data pulled from the DB. It's bad syntax and putting the back-slash in between the quotes breaks it.

Can anyone tell me how to do this please? Or am I even correct as to think this is what I should be doing?

Much thanks.

**EDIT:** PHP code for blog post insert

```
if (isset($_POST['blogpost'])) {


    $nowdate = new DateTime('NOW');
    $thisdate = $nowdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $post = $_POST['blogpost'];
    $title = $_POST['posttitle'];
    $status = 'yes';




    try {

        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO blogposts(posttext, thisdate, posttitle, active) VALUES(:post, :postdate, :posttitle, :status)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':post'=>$post, ':postdate'=>$thisdate, ':posttitle'=>$title, ':status'=>$status
        ));

      //echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        echo 'died';


    };

}
```

Comment: Try 2 backslashes ! Also I think you should remove `\"` instead of \.

Comment: `stripslashes()` is the function you're looking for. But it would be best if you showed your code for inserting and retrieving from the database. If you do it properly you shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @Barmar I updated with insert code, i figure even if it works, your pointers will help. :)

Comment: Prepared statements shouldn't add any escaping, so I don't think that code does it. So it probably has something to do with the way the post is submitted from the browser. Is it an ordinary form or AJAX? Maybe TinyMCE is doing it? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm affraid that TinyMCE is the culprit. But maybe it's an intended behaviour...

Comment: @barmar I thought it wasn't my statement, I do escaping for some other parts like the login system. It may be TinyMCE, although it's confusing me why its only affected it when i've move from heart internet to oneandone. Thank you or your time though. :)

Comment: @HamZa if you want to put it in an answer i'll accept Hamza?

Comment: Did you use your own copy of TinyMCE, or the hosted version?

Comment: @TryingToBeZen no it's ok. btw Lukas answer should do the job.

Comment: @Barmar My own version, as in I downloaded it, and installe the JQuery version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$cleanpost = str_replace('\"', '',$post);
```

Comment: It'd be worth investigating how these got into the database in the first place. Maybe [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are turned on for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stripslashes()` to unescape the string.

```
$post = stripslashes($post);
```